# Peoplepicker-searchadforests for MOSS SP2 in FBA site?

Tags: 2007, administration

My Sharepoint farm on XXXdmz.org and all my staff on XXX.org domain. XXX.org is the one way trust domain. I am able to find and add XXXhq.org users  in "Local ussers and groups", but not able to find in sharepoint people picker.

I did following steps still not resolved.

1. stsadm -o setapppassword -passowrd

   1. stsadm -o setproperty -url http://mywebapplicationUrl.com -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:XXX.org", XXX\user,

I am troubleshooting this since  morning... not resolved..

Answer (score 0):

The format of the command is "domain:example.com,username,password".

Comment: even i tried this..

Comment: Please make sure the appropriate ports are open from your DMZ *SharePoint Server(s)* to your internal Domain Controllers.  See http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2009/01/21/people-picker-port-protocol-requirements.aspx.

Comment: is different ports than the Local ussers and group access?. Because I can access users from "Local ussers and group" in the farm. Not in SharePoint picker

Comment: Take a look at the blog post.  Try telneting from the SharePoint Server to some of the ports on your internal Domain Controllers.  If that doesn't work, then the People Picker cannot reach the internal Domain Controllers.

Comment: @Travor: I got interesting thing in ULS logs... Why peoplepicker searching SQL server when search for domain user?  see these errors    Error in searching user 'ehq\auseovach' : System.Web.HttpException: Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locatin